# Can't store return value from which function in R

Tags: r

Hi everyone so I'm very new to R - installed RStudio last week.

I'm trying to store the coordinate of an element in the dataframe other_list below into the variable beta1, but I keep getting the error: "object 'beta1' not found".

```
for (val in 1:length(sampledata)) {
  if (sampledata[val] %in% other_list)
    beta1 = which(other_list == sampledata[val])
  add_values = dataset1[c(beta1), c("name", "gender", "age")]
   rbind(dataset2, add_values)
}
```

Anyone have an explanation for why beta1 doesn't get recognized in the dataset1 brackets?

Thank you!

Comment: You never pre-define `beta1` until the `sampledata[val]` condition is met. Worse, the next time in the loop when the condition is not met, `beta1` exists based on the previous loop. You need to determine a pre-condition of `else` version of your conditional. BTW: iteratively adding rows to a `data.frame` is really bad practice, consider adding a new (1 row or so) `data.frame` to a `list` and do a single `do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)` post-loop.

Comment: I'd think you could "brace" things, adding a left-brace `{` before `beta1=`, and a close-brace after `rbind`. There's not need to add values if the condition is not met. (BTW: you `rbind` but never save its value, so `rbind(...)` throws its return value away every time (your loop is spinning wildly, copying memory unnecessarily, and in the end does nothing.)

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions.

**First**, you don't define what `beta1` should be if the condition is not met, *yet you try to use it anyway*. This is bad in both the initial case (`'beta1' not found`) and in the next case where `beta1` was defined on a previous loop. *Your data will be wrong.* I suggest you only use `beta1` if relevant, try this:

```r
for (val in 1:length(sampledata)) {
  beta1 = which(other_list == sampledata[val])
  if (length(beta1)) {
    add_values = dataset1[c(beta1), c("name", "gender", "age")]
    rbind(dataset2, add_values)
  }
}
```

(This is still wrong.)

**Second**, you call `rbind` but ignore its return value. Most functions in R are *functional* in that they have no side-effect. `rbind` does not change any of the data, it returns the concatenated data. So you need to capture it:

```r
for (val in 1:length(sampledata)) {
  beta1 = which(other_list == sampledata[val])
  if (length(beta1)) {
    add_values = dataset1[c(beta1), c("name", "gender", "age")]
    dataset2 = rbind(dataset2, add_values)
  }
}
```

(This is still bad.)

Slightly-**third** ... this is not strictly broken but can be if you intend to "automate" this. The premise of `1:length(x)` is that it should allow you to iterate over indices of a vector ... but if `x` is empty, then `1:length(x)` reduces to `1:0` which does *not* return an empty vector:

```r
1:length(c())
# [1] 1 0
```

which means that your loop will try to find both `sampledata[1]` (which does not exist) and `sampledata[0]` (which is also length 0, and will break many functions).

It is better to use either `for (i in seq_len(length(x)))` or `for (i in seq_along(x))`, both will do nothing if `x` is empty,

```r
for (i in seq_along(10:11)) print(i)
# [1] 1
# [1] 2
for (i in seq_along(integer(0))) print(i)
#### nothing done
```

**Fourth**, though is *how* `rbind` does things *functionally*: it makes a complete copy of the entire `data.frame`. This means that if you start with (say) 1000 rows and then add 2 more rows, then you have those 1000 rows in memory *twice*. Eventually it is garbage-collected (cleared from memory), but that takes time. Now on the next iteration of the `for` loop, you want to add another 3 rows; this time it makes a complete copy of the now-current 1002 rows so that they now occur in memory *twice*. Do this enough times and your time to calculate is mostly spent in copying all of that data around. (This is precisely the problem discussed in *Chapter 2: Growing objects* in the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf).)

The fix is generally to take all of the rows to be appended and only concatenate them once. I think this would change your code to something like:

```r
list_of_frames = list()
for (val in 1:length(sampledata)) {
  beta1 = which(other_list == sampledata[val])
  if (length(beta1)) {
    add_values = dataset1[c(beta1), c("name", "gender", "age")]
    list_of_frames = c(list_of_frames, add_values)
  }
}
dataset2 = do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)
```

If you're using other packages, this might be easier with one of these lines of code *instead*:

```r
dataset2 = dplyr::bind_rows(list_of_frames)
dataset2 = data.table::rbindlist(list_of_frames)
```

This should be "good enough".

You *could* go one step further (to a **Fifth** point) to use an R-idiomatic `lapply`, though, something like:

```r
list_of_frames = lapply(seq_along(sampledata), function(ind) {
  beta1 = which(other_list == sampledata[ind])
  if (length(beta1)) dataset1[beta1, c("name", "gender", "age")]
})
### or better yet
list_of_frames = lapply(sampledata, function(sampdat) {
  beta1 = which(other_list == sampdat)
  if (length(beta1)) dataset1[beta1, c("name", "gender", "age")]
})
### then
dataset2 = do.call(rbind, list_of_frames)
```

Yes, there will likely be elements of `list_of_frames` that are `NULL`, and the `do.call(rbind, ...)` part deals with that *just fine*.